# Why can't I capture my first Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to just catch my first Pokemon and I can't for some reason. From what I've read I should be able to see the three basic Pokemon to choose from and catch one but I can't see them.

I can only see three pulsing circles and the app appears to be stuck on map view. I've tried clicking or walking over the circles but nothing happens.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to restart the game and try again. There is a huge load on the servers as they are adding new countries to the list where Pokemon GO is available.

If restarting the game doesn't work, reinstall it. If that doesn't work, have patience and try in a few days.

Comment: Just to add, I got it stuck because of disabled GPS, after enabling it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Now the game is deployed almost everywhere, so you can reinstall it, and you'll be able to catch millions of Pokemon ^^

By the way, if you want to have Pikachu instead of the 3 other starters, you just have to walk a little bit (like 5-10 mins), and you'll see him spawning near to the starters ^^